# How to programatically set the field value for file_field_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, attachment

I have a Rails form that has a file_field_tag:

```
<%= file_field_tag :file %>
```

There are other items in the form. In case of error on those other items, I want to redirect back to the form, but not make the user re-choose the file.  In the controller I do something like:

```
@file = params[:file]
```

Now when I send them back to the form I do

```
<%= file_field_tag :file, value: @file %>
```

But this doesn't work.  How do I pass the file chosen back to the form?

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to keep file field value when validation failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981119/how-to-keep-file-field-value-when-validation-failed)

Answer (score 0):

Due to security reasons - you cannot set value for file input,
for better user experience be there validation errors - you can save already uploaded file to a temporary location and model and pass its id to your form in a hidden field.